# How to get index and the range of a div element from a group of divs using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have a group of tokenized divs like the following.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div> Barrack </div>
<div> Obama </div> 
<div> was </div>
<div> the </div>
<div> president </div>
<div> of </div>
<div> the </div>
<div> United </div>
<div> States </div>
<div> from </div>
<div> the </div>
<div> year </div>
<div> 2012 </div>
<div> to </div>
<div> 2016 </div>
<div> . </div>

<button id="btnClick"> Click me </button>

<script>
$(function(){

$('#btnClick').click(function(){
var selection = window.getSelection();
alert(selection);
});

});
</script>
```

I have tried the above

1) I want to get the index of divs when I click on multiple divs on mouse click event.
Example is if I click on div which contains Barrack and 2012, I am not able to get the selected div's index.

2) If I select the div which contains both Barrack and Obama
I want the range of the div, something like:
startIndex -> 0 and length -> 2. 
Where startIndex = "Barrack" is the 0th div and it ranges 2 divs Barrack and Obama.

Comment: Bind a click event on the divs and then store the index when its clicked.

Comment: @HarryBomrah I have binded the click event, please check above, but I am unable to get the index and the range of the selected div.

Comment: you never bind click on `div`, you only bind on button click

Comment: @SudarpoChong So I should bind an event for the click on div?

Comment: What happens when user clicks third time?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick. Is this what you want?

```
  var selectedDiv = [];

  $("div").click(function() {
    selectedDiv.push($(this).text());
  });
```

### EDIT

Get the index of div

```
 var indexNo = $("div").index($(this));
```

```js
$(function() {
  var selectedDiv = [];

  $("div").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    var indexNo = $("div").index($(this));
    selectedDiv.push(indexNo);
    // selectedDiv.push($(this).text());
  });

  $('#btnClick').click(function() {
    // var selection = window.getSelection();
    alert(selectedDiv);
  });

});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  background: #00f;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div.selected {
  background: #f0f;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div> Barrack </div>
<div> Obama </div>
<div> was </div>
<div> the </div>
<div> president </div>
<div> of </div>
<div> the </div>
<div> United </div>
<div> States </div>
<div> from </div>
<div> the </div>
<div> year </div>
<div> 2012 </div>
<div> to </div>
<div> 2016 </div>
<div> . </div>

<button id="btnClick"> Click me </button>
```

Comment: I want the index of the div when I click on the div

Comment: Thanks, this is a pointer in the right direction, And the second part of the question is if I select multiple divs I want to get the range of the the first div I selected and the last div I selected.

Comment: I dont understand the 2nd part. how do you select multiple divs? isnt the same as 1st question?

Comment: in this sample, if i select obama and president, i get 1,4

Comment: It seems to be pushing the indices twice in the array on mouse click

Answer (score 1):

Use the **slice** function of jQuery.

```
.slice( start [, end ] )
```

> **start** ➡ An integer indicating the 0-based position at which the elements begin to be selected. If negative, it indicates an offset from the end of the set.
>
> **end** ➡ An integer indicating the 0-based position at which the elements stop being selected. If negative, it indicates an offset from
>   the end of the set. If omitted, the range continues until the end of
>   the set.

For your case, to select only **Barack** & **Obama** from multiple **div** elements, I would write something like:

```
$( "div" ).slice(0, 1).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

[jQuery.slice() method](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

Comment: But how would I get those indices 0 , 1 (start and end ) for the slice function parameters?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee  For that you would enclose all of your **div** elements into a single/master **div** element and then use the **.slice(start, end)** feature on that master div element to select the specific divs that you want to work upon.

Comment: but this still doesn't answer my question

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Don't you want to select multiple div elements based on their indices or the range they cover among several other div elements ?
Here's a link for clarification:➡  https://pastebin.com/kEBeXWK4

Comment: But you seem to hardcode the values 0 and 1 to the slice function parameters instead of calculating them?

Comment: The indices 0 and 1 are the indices representing your inner div elements when you initialize a **.slice()** jQuery method. And no, slicing your divs do not pop off the div elements from the collection. It simply isolates them from other divs for the sake of applying a new change.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee , Have a look at **jQuery's.find()** method. Maybe, that's what you're expecting. Since **.find()** allows you to select an object and browse through its descendants.  https://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
<div class="findIndex">
  <div> the </div>
  <div> United </div>
  <div> States </div>
  <div> from </div>
  <div> the </div>
  <div> year </div>
  <div> 2012 </div>
  <div> to </div>
  <div> 2016 </div>
  <div> . </div>
</div>
<button id="btnClick"> Click me </button>

var indexRange = [];
$(".findIndex div").on("click",function(){
  if(indexRange.length == 0){
      indexRange[0] = $(this).index();
  }else{
    indexRange[1] = $(this).index();
  }
})

$("#btnClick").on("click",function(){
    if(indexRange.length == 2){
        alert("Start Index:" + indexRange[0] + "\n" + "End Index:" + indexRange[1] + "\n" + "Length:" + ((indexRange[1] - indexRange[0]) + 1));
    }else{
        alert("Please select start and end first.");
    }
    indexRange = Array();
})
```

Here is the fiddle : 
https://jsfiddle.net/vsmdcc3L/

Answer (score 1):

You can try `$.each()` or `$(selector).each()`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var lastIdx = 0;
        $("div").each(function(idx, item){
            $(this).click(function(){
                if (idx > lastIdx) {
                    console.log("start:" + lastIdx);
                    console.log("length:" + (idx - lastIdx + 1));
                } 
                lastIdx = idx;
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```